# How to show value given from master to Slave's memory as Modbus slave app C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, modbus

im quite new in this modbus and C# world. I've been working on ModbusRTU with this kind of connection between apps (see below)

`miniPC(winforms app) <=> Arduino Mega(Modbus Master) <=> Arduino nano(Modbus Slavetext`

at this moment, i knew that there's no way that could be 2 masters in ModbusRTU connection. so I'm setting up my C# winform app as a slave to get the data from arduino mega(Master).

as my experiment begin, I already know how to store a data as slave to memory address as it will be read by the master using code below. (I'm using NModbus4 Class library)

```
public static ModbusSlave SLAVE;

private void myform_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){

//other code//

SLAVE = ModbusSerialSlave.CreateRtu(10, myserialPort);
SLAVE.DataStore = DataStoreFactory.CreateDefaultDataStore();

slaveThread = new Thread(SLAVE.Listen);
slaveThread.Start();
}

private void SendVal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

SLAVE.DataStore.HoldingRegisters[1] = start_st; //sending some value
SLAVE.DataStore.HoldingRegisters[2] = finish_st; //sending another value
```

everything's above works fine, until i want to reverse the operation with my C# app that has to read the value given by the Arduino Mega(Master) in a certain address and show it to multiple variable.

let's say there's a 4 variable of IR_sensor called

```
ushort[] IR_Vals;

IR_Vals[0];
IR_Vals[1];
IR_Vals[2];
IR_Vals[3];
```

because ModbusSerialSlave doesn't have `.readHoldingRegisters()` method to read just like the master.

does everyone know how to deal with this? maybe some example? will appricate for help :))

Comment: I've never used NModbus4 Class library, but...
Whenever I want to send data using MODBUS, I use SerialPort from IO.Ports.
You can easily write 3rd function, which is ReadHoldingRegisters();

What do you use to send data between your master and slave?

Comment: As per [the spec](https://www.modbus.org/docs/Modbus_over_serial_line_V1_02.pdf) "Slave nodes will not typically transmit data without a request from the master node" so a slave cannot generally send info to a Master (the Master must write it to the slave). You will need to configure your master (the Mega) to write the required data to a holding register on your C# Slave (and you can then retrieve the value from the `DataStore`)